# after dropping the image from panel to canvas, how can the dropped image be rotated in canvas using flex4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

this is the code for 3d rotation

```
<s:Rotate3D id="rotate3DX"
                    target="{image}"
                    angleXFrom="0"
                    angleXTo="360"
                    duration="2000"
                    autoCenterTransform="true" />


    <s:Rotate3D id="rotate3DY"
                target="{image}"
                angleYFrom="0"
                angleYTo="360"
                duration="2000"
                autoCenterTransform="true" />

    <s:Rotate3D id="rotate3DZ"
                target="{image}"
                angleZFrom="0"
                angleZTo="360"
                duration="2000"
                autoCenterTransform="true" />

</fx:Declarations>
```

this the cod for drag and drop

```
private function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var dragInitiator:Image=Image(event.currentTarget); 
                var ds:DragSource = new DragSource(); 
                ds.addData(dragInitiator, "img"); 
                DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, ds, event); 

            }

            private function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void
            {
                if (event.dragSource.hasFormat("img")) 
                    DragManager.acceptDragDrop(Canvas(event.currentTarget)); 

            }
            private function dropHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
                if (event.dragSource.hasFormat("img")) {
                    var draggedImage:Image = 
                        event.dragSource.dataForFormat('img') as Image;
                    var dropCanvas:Canvas = event.currentTarget as Canvas;

                    // Since this is a copy, create a new object to 
                    // add to the drop target.
                    var newImage:Image=new Image();
                    newImage.source = draggedImage.source;
                    newImage.x = dropCanvas.mouseX;
                    newImage.y = dropCanvas.mouseY;
                    newImage.height=200;
                    newImage.width=200;
                    newImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseDownHandler);
                    newImage.addEventListener(DragEvent.DRAG_COMPLETE, dragCompleteHandler);
                    dropCanvas.addChild(newImage);
                    newImage.id=draggedImage.id;
                }
            }


            public function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                canvas1.graphics.clear();
            }
            private function dragCompleteHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
                var draggedImage:Image = 
                    event.dragInitiator as Image;
                var dragInitCanvas:Canvas = 
                    event.dragInitiator.parent as Canvas;

                if (event.action == DragManager.MOVE)
                    dragInitCanvas.removeChild(draggedImage);
            }
```

the images are

```
<mx:Panel width="216" height="349" title="Parts" color="#010101"
                      cornerRadius="10">
                <mx:Image source="images\8.png" 
                          width="128" height="76" 
                          mouseMove="mouseDownHandler(event)"
                          id="image"


                         />
                <mx:Image source="images\10.jpg" 
                          width="110" height="87" 
                          mouseMove="mouseDownHandler(event)"/>
                <mx:Image source="images\9.jpg" 
                          width="111" height="88" 
                          mouseMove="mouseDownHandler(event)"/>
            </mx:Panel>
```

the canvas in which images are dropped is

```
        <mx:Canvas id="canvas1"
                   height="349" width="1080" 
                   backgroundColor="#BFBDBD"
                   cornerRadius="10"
                   borderColor="#000000"
                   borderVisible="true"
                   dropShadowVisible="true"
                   dragEnter="dragEnterHandler(event)"
                   dragDrop="dropHandler(event)"
                  >




            <mx:ControlBar width="100%" cornerRadius="0">
                <s:Button id="buttonX"
                          label="Rotate3D X-axis"
                          click="rotate3DX.play();" />
                <s:Button id="buttonY"
                          label="Rotate3D Y-axis"
                          click="rotate3DY.play();" />
                <s:Button id="bButtonZ"
                          label="Rotate3D Z-axis"
                          click="rotate3DZ.play();" />
            </mx:ControlBar>

        </mx:Canvas>
```

i want to rotate the image after dropping them in the canvas.i am able to rotate them in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are binding the target of the effect.  Simply switching the ID from one component to another won't actually work.  The reference to the original image is what is actually bound. You would be better off programmatically switching the target of the effect in the dropHandler method.

```
// DON'T DO THIS
newImage.id=draggedImage.id;

// DO THIS
rotate3DY.target = newImage;
rotate3DZ.target = newImage;
```

Comment: i am able to rotate the last dropped image in canvas..now i want to select one image out of multiple images and rotate that particular image..can u help me on that?

Comment: You have to have a way to determine which image you want to select.  For example, you could click and image and on the clickHandler you could set the target of the effects to be that image.  

Long story short - just be sure to set the target on the effects to the image you actually want to rotate.